# T-SQL: Cannot pass concatenated string as argument to stored procedure

Tags: sql-server-2005, t-sql

**Scenario**:
Need to pass *n* arguments to a stored procedure. One of the arguments is of type `varchar(x)`. That varchar argument needs to be constructed from a handful of other varchar variables. This problem uses SQL Server 2005, but this behaviour applies to all versions of SQL Server.

**Setup**:

```
DECLARE @MyString varchar(500), @MyBar varchar(10), @MyFoo varchar(10)

SELECT @MyBar= 'baz ' 
SELECT @MyFoo= 'bat ' 

-- try calling this stored procedure!
EXEC DoSomeWork @MsgID, 'Hello ' + @MyBar + '" world! "' + @MyFoo + '".'
```

This produces the exception in SQL Server: `Incorrect syntax near '+'`. Typically you might think that the datatype would be wrong (i.e. the variables are of different types, but that would produce a different error message).

Here's a correct implementation that compiles without error:

```
SELECT @MyString= 'Hello ' + @MyBar + '" world! "' + @MyFoo + '".';

EXEC DoSomeWork @ID, @MyString
```

**Question**: **Why** is it that T-SQL can't handle the concatenation of a varchar as an argument? It knows the types, as they were declared properly as varchar.

Answer (score 26, accepted):

The EXECUTE statement simply has a different grammar then other statements like SELECT and SET. For instance, observe the syntax section at the top of the following two pages.

EXECUTE statement: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188332.aspx

SET statement: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189484.aspx

The syntax for EXECUTE only accepts a **value**

> [[@parameter =] {**value** | @variable
>   [OUTPUT] | [DEFAULT]]

Whereas the syntax for SET accepts an **expression**

> {@local_variable = **expression**}

A value is basically just a hard coded constant, but an expression is going to be evaluated. It's like having the varchar 'SELECT 1 + 1'. It's just a varchar value right now. However, you can *evaluate* the string like this:

```
EXEC('SELECT 1 + 1')
```

I suppose all I'm pointing out is that the EXEC command doesn't allow expressions by definition, which you apparently found out already. I don't know what the intention of the developers of T-SQL where when they made it that way. I suppose the grammar would just get out of hand if you where allowed to throw subqueries within subqueries in the parameter list of a stored procedure.

T-SQL Expression: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190286.aspx

Comment: The website referred to in this comment is no longer up.

Comment: Maybe `EXEC` only permits string *variables* because stored procedures can have `OUT` parameters for which expressions make no sense. But those don't work with string *literals* either...

Answer (score 2):

You cannot do something like this either

```
exec SomeProc getdate()
```

you have to put all that stuff in a param like you are doing at your bottom query
It might be because it is non deterministic (at least for functions)

Answer (score 2):

It's a limitation on the EXEC statement. See **[The curse and blessings of dynamic SQL](http://www.sommarskog.se/dynamic_sql.html)** for more information.

Comment: What does this issue have to do with dynamic SQL?