# Why does concatenating strings in the argument of EXEC sometimes cause a syntax error in T-SQL?

Tags: t-sql, exec, concatenation

In MS SQL Server Management Studio 2005, running this code

```
EXEC('SELECT * FROM employees WHERE employeeID = ' + CAST(3 AS VARCHAR))
```

gives this error: `Incorrect syntax near 'CAST'`

However, if I do this, it works:

```
DECLARE @temp VARCHAR(4000)
SET @temp = 'SELECT * FROM employees WHERE employeeID = ' + CAST(3 AS VARCHAR)
EXEC(@temp)
```

I found an explanation here: [T-SQL: Cannot pass concatenated string as argument to stored procedure](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1044831/t-sql-cannot-pass-concatenated-string-as-argument-to-stored-procedure)

According to the accepted answer, `EXEC` can take a local variable or a value as its argument, but not an expression.

However, if that's the case, why does this work:

```
DECLARE @temp VARCHAR(4000)
SET @temp = CAST(3 AS VARCHAR)
EXEC('SELECT * FROM employees WHERE employeeID = ' + @temp)
```

`'SELECT * FROM employees WHERE employeeID = ' + @temp` sure looks like an expression to me, but the code executes with no errors.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

[The documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188332.aspx) states that `EXEC` can take either a string variable, a constant T-SQL string, or combinations/concatenations of both of them.

Your "why does this work" example uses a concatenation of a constant T-SQL string and a string variable, and so is perfectly legal.

Comment: Implied but omitted here is why the failing cases do not work: because they involve expressions, which are neither of the allowed things mentioned here, so they can't be concatenated with either of those other things.