# How can I insert text, from a subquery, in a function request

Tags: sql, sql-server, function

I'm using a function on the Master database (xp_fileexist) to check if a folder is empty or not. If it's empty I want a 0, otherwise a 1.

If I hardcode the folder name ('C:\Import\2016-01-01\Transaction') it works fine. What doesn't work for me, is having the date as a variable, as the date changes from time to time. For the variable, I use this:

'C:\Import\The Netherlands\'+CAST((select workingdate from system..tmpworkingdate) AS VARCHAR(10))+'\Transaction(BP)'

This is the code I've tried:

```
CREATE TABLE #temp (FileExists int, IsDirectory int, ParentDirExists int)

INSERT INTO #temp

EXEC master..xp_fileexist ('C:\Import\'+CAST((select workingdate from system..tmpworkingdate) AS VARCHAR(10))+'\Transaction(BP)')

IF EXISTS(SELECT IsDirectory FROM #temp WHERE IsDirectory=1)

PRINT 1

ELSE

PRINT 0

DROP TABLE #temp
```

```
Error: Msg 102, Level 15, State 1, Line 5 Incorrect syntax near
'C:\Import\The Netherlands\'. Msg 156, Level 15, State 1, Line 5
Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'AS'.
```

Does anyone have a clue?

Comment: This is clearly not MySQL so I changed the tag.  Please tag with the database you are really using.

Comment: Thanks, pretty new here, so I guess I've added that one by mistake;)

Comment: Can someone who hasn't voted too much today please vote as a dupe of this? [Why does concatenating strings in the argument of EXEC sometimes cause a syntax error in T-SQL?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2646492/why-does-concatenating-strings-in-the-argument-of-exec-sometimes-cause-a-syntax)

Answer (score 1):

`EXEC` doesn't allow string manipulations (or any expression evaluation).  Define the value beforehand:

```
DECLARE @filename VARCHAR(MAX);
SET @filename = 'C:\Import\'+CAST((select workingdate from system..tmpworkingdate) AS VARCHAR(10))+'\Transaction(BP)';

EXEC master..xp_fileexist (@filename);
```

That said, you should use `CONVERT()` or `FORMAT()` to be sure you get the format you really want.  You wouldn't want system changes to totally break this code.

EDIT:

Argg!  I didn't realize that `EXEC master..xp_fileexist` doesn't even allow string variables on the execution line.  So, you have to do the whole thing as dynamic SQL:

```
DECLARE @sql NVARCHAR(MAX) = 'EXEC master..xp_fileexist ''' + @filename + '''';

EXEC(@sql);
```

(There are examples on the web that do use variables, so maybe this depends on the SQL Server version.)

Comment: Is it the parens?