# Concatenating literals with expressions using t-sql 2005 and above

Tags: t-sql, stored-procedures, syntax

I hope someone can shed some light on this.  I can't believe I never noticed this issue before.  It's really irritating me.

Why is it not possible to do inline concatenation using stored procs (I haven't tried with functions yet)?

Look at this example I created.  This will not complete with execution.  It will fail on line 5.

It seems like overkill to make the developer have to create a variable possibly and issue a `set` command anywhere that it is required to insert some concatenated value into a sp.

Please tell me I'm over looking something.

```
DECLARE @WORLD NVARCHAR(MAX)
SET @WORLD = 'WORLD'
PRINT  'HELLO ' + @WORLD

exec sp_profileColumn 'dbo' + '.' + @WORLD --THIS STATEMENT FAILS

set @WORLD = 'dbo' + '.' + @WORLD

exec sp_profileColumn @WORLD  --LOGICALLY THIS STATEMENT IS THE SAME AS LINE 5, CORRECT?
```

Comment: Related http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1044831/t-sql-cannot-pass-concatenated-string-as-argument-to-stored-procedure

Comment: Good find for the related question.  It makes mine a duplicate I suppose.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I agree that it is unfortunate, but it has been that way for a long time in SQL Server.