# Unable to get convert() function to provide correct parameter to a stored procedure

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, stored-procedures, parameter-passing

I have the following function:

```
create procedure log_message
  @p as varchar(20),
  @r as varchar(20),
  @l as varchar(20),
  @m as varchar(max)
as
begin
  insert into logs (time_stamp, program, routine, location, [message])
  values (getdate(), @p, @r, @l, @m)
end
```

I can log a message easily with:

```
exec dbo.log_message 'test code', 'this routine', 'right here', 'some message'
```

This works great.

However, I get an error when I try this:

```
declare @x int;
set @x = 3
exec dbo.log_message 'test code', 'this routine', 'right here', convert(varchar(10), @x)
```

I can fix this by invoking it like this:

```
declare @x int;
declare @m varchar(10);
set @x = 3;
set @m = convert(varchar(10), @x)
exec dbo.log_message 'test code', 'this routine', 'right here', @m
```

But this seems spectacularly obtuse that I have trouble believing one can't just write it in the more natural way.  What am I missing?

EVEN WORSE! As I'm playing with this trying to figure out what works and what doesn't, I realized that this does not work:

```
exec dbo.log_message 'test code', 'this routine', 'right here', 'a' + 'b'
```

My first thought is ... it can't possibly work like this.  Is there another way to invoke stored procedures in SQL that works like normal programming languages?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1044831/t-sql-cannot-pass-concatenated-string-as-argument-to-stored-procedure

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sorry but you cannot pass a **EXPRESSION** as a parameter to a SP. You can only use **VALUES**