# DATE parameter passed as 'YYYY-MM-DD' not being properly evaluated by a stored procedure?

Tags: sql, sql-server

Given:

```
    CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[sp_func]
                      @StartDate            DATE
                    , @EndDate              DATE
    AS
      select * from [TRANS] where
(@StartDate IS NULL OR [TransDate] >= @StartDate) AND (@EndDate IS NULL OR [TransDate] <= @EndDate)
```

Both this:

```
declare @StartDate DATE = '2015-01-01'
declare @EndDate DATE = '2015-12-31'
exec dbo.sp_func @StartDate, @EndDate
```

And this:

```
declare @StartDate DATE = NULL
declare @EndDate DATE = NULL
exec dbo.sp_func @StartDate, @EndDate
```

...return rows as expected.

However, both of these calls return 0 rows:

```
exec dbo.sp_func '2015-01-01', '2015-12-31'
exec dbo.sp_func NULL, NULL
```

Am I fundamentally misunderstanding something here?  As far as I can recall, I’ve always called sp’s passing dates like 'YYYY-MM-DD' with absolutely no issues.

Possibly related...this:

```
select CAST('2015-01-01' AS DATE), CAST('2015-12-31' AS DATE)
```

returns:

```
2015-01-01          2015-12-31
```

Whereas this:

```
exec dbo.sp_func CAST('2015-01-01' AS DATE), CAST('2015-12-31' AS DATE)
```

returns:

```
Incorrect syntax near '2015-01-01'.
```

I feel like I'm taking crazy pills.

**I discovered the problem, it was stupidity.**

Not shown in the example, I had other parameters in my production code, one of which was:

@JobClass VARCHAR(10) = 'PRODUCTION'

What I had been doing wrong in my test code was passing NULL to this, and incorrectly thinking that a passed NULL to this would instead default to 'PRODUCTION', whereas this defaulting only happens when the parameter *is not passed at all*.  Which I knew of course.  One of those days.

Comment: Sidenote: please avoid prefixing your stored procs with `sp_`. See this article by Aaron Bertrand: http://sqlperformance.com/2012/10/t-sql-queries/sp_prefix

Comment: exec dbo.sp_func '2015-01-01', '2015-12-31'

works for me.

Is it possible that you're doing something strange like accidentally calling the wrong SP?

Comment: What version of SQL Server?

Comment: We all have those days!

Comment: You can't pass complex arguments to a procedure. That's why the cast doesn't work.

Comment: "You can't pass complex arguments to a procedure."  Interesting...is there any documentation on what you can and cannot pass?  I think you can pass a GETDATE()-1 can you not?

Comment: @Donnelle - thanks, I'm going to check out that article for sure.

Comment: @tbone I was going to refer you to the BOL entry for EXEC. But just check this question instead: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1044831/t-sql-cannot-pass-concatenated-string-as-argument-to-stored-procedure

Answer (score 1):

A couple of things , I would re-write the whole proc as below:

**Procedure Definition**

```
CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[usp_Proc]  --<-- do not use sp_ 
  @StartDate DATE = NULL
, @EndDate   DATE = NULL
AS
BEGIN
 SET NOCOUNT ON;

 DECLARE @sql NVARCHAR(MAX);

SET @sql = N' select * from [TRANS] where 1 = 1 '
        +  CASE WHEN  @StartDate IS NOT NULL 
           THEN N' AND [TransDate] >= @StartDate' ELSE N' ' END
        +  CASE WHEN  @EndDate IS NOT NULL 
           THEN N' AND [TransDate] <= @EndDate  ' ELSE N' ' END

Execute sp_executesql @sql
                    ,N'@StartDate DATE,@EndDate DATE '  
                    ,@StartDate
                    ,@EndDate  
END
```

**Execute Procedure**

```
 exec dbo.usp_Proc '20150101', '20151231'  --<-- Pass date in ANSI format 'YYYYMMDD'
```

Answer (score 0):

How about specifying the variable names and values like this:

```
EXECUTE dbo.sp_func @StartDate='2015-01-01',@EndDate='2015-12-31'
```

Works on my machine... :)